# Subset of $\mathbb{R}$ without a countable neighborhood base

Tags: general-topology

An exercise in Ronnie Brown's *Topology and Groupoids* asks the reader to find a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (with usual topology) which does not have a countable neighborhood base.*

**My ideas:** The subset must be uncountable, since otherwise the unions of countable neighborhood bases of each point would be countable. My intuition was to use $(0,1) \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Any neighborhood base of $(0,1) \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ must have elements that exclude each closed (in $\mathbb{R}$) subset of $(0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$. For instance, given a sequence of rational numbers $q_n$ which has only rational limit points $L \subset \mathbb{Q}$, our neighborhood base would have to have an element that does not meet $\{q_n : n \geq 0 \} \cup L$. But I was having trouble using this line of thinking to show that such a neighborhood base must be uncountable.

---

*For completeness, my understanding of a neighborhood base of a set $S$ is a collection $N_\alpha$ of neighborhoods of $S$ (i.e. sets containing an open set containing $S$), such that for any neighborhood $N$ of $S$, there is some $\alpha$ such that $N \supset N_\alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The subset must be uncountable, since otherwise the unions of countable neighborhood bases of each point would be countable.

That's a mistake. If we take for example $S = \mathbb{N}$, you get a neighbourhood base by taking the product of neighbourhood bases of the points, not the union.

And that gives you an example, for every function $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to (0,+\infty)$ you get a neighbourhood

$$V_f = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} (n - f(n), n+ f(n)),$$

and you can show that no countable system of neighbourhoods is a neighbourhood basis.

If $\{ U_k : k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a countable system of neighbourhoods of $\mathbb{N}$, you can construct a function $f$ such that $V_f \not \supset U_m$ for all $m$. Without loss of generality, suppose that $U_k \subset B_{2^{-k-1}}(\mathbb{N})$ so that the neighbourhoods of the points of $\mathbb{N}$ are disjoint. Then we get a function $f_k \colon \mathbb{N} \to (0,+\infty)$ via

$$f_k(n) = \sup \{ \varepsilon > 0 : (n-\varepsilon, n+\varepsilon) \subset U_k\}$$

and have $V_{f_k} \subset U_k$. Let

$$f(n) = 2^{-n-1}\min \{ f_k(n) : k \leqslant n\}.$$

Then $U_k \not \subset V_f$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Great answer. One point of confusion: instead of assuming $U_k \subset B_{2^{-k-1}}(\mathbb{N})$ it would be sufficient that $U_k \subset B_{2^{-1}}(\mathbb{N})$, right? 

(Interesting that it seems that the countability of the set in question is actually an asset in this counterexample. I'm not sure how I would construct something analogous for an uncountable set.)

Comment: Right, to separate the points it suffices to have them all contained in $B_{1/2}(\mathbb{N})$. I just let the radii shrink out of habit. Constructing something analogous for uncountable sets - leaving aside things like $\bigcup [n-1/4,n+1/4]$ - is more difficult indeed. If we have a countable sequence of open "holes" such that it doesn't accumulate at a point of the set, we can make essentially the same construction, but for uglier sets, nothing springs to mind after some short thinking.